# how to resize dropdown menu bootstrap full page

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-5

You can see from photo

[zabubi solution network platform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfqA4.png)

dropdown menu "no request for collaboration to be accepted" on top it, menu has size of half page. I can't seem to set responsive, dropdown menu full size page even if page resizes.
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the CDN, then you'll need to manually set the `min-width` on the `dropdown-menu` class, which by default is set as `10rem`. Then you'd need to set the `max-width` or `width` on the `dropdown-menu` class. You might need to use `!important` for the changes to take priority over the default bootstrap classes.

Comment: OK, I set min-width to full window when page resize minus margin o padding.

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to specify, you'll need to set the min-width on the `dropdown-menu` itself, not the window (edited the answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
function fixMenuWidth()
{
    var win = $(this); //this = window
    winWidth = win.width();
    barMarginLeftWidth = parseInt($('.topbarcontainer').css("margin-left"));
    barMarginRightWidth = parseInt($('.topbarcontainer').css("margin-right"));
    extraWidth = 25;
    extraAccountWidth = extraWidth + 42;
    var widthRequest = winWidth - barMarginLeftWidth - barMarginRightWidth - extraWidth;
    var widthAccount = winWidth - barMarginLeftWidth - barMarginRightWidth - extraAccountWidth;
    $(".menuRequestCowork").css('min-width',widthRequest+'px');
    $(".menuAccount").css('min-width',widthAccount+'px');
}

$(window).on('resize', function(){
    fixMenuWidth();
});

fixMenuWidth();
});
```

this code check window size and then calculate width subtracting margin left and right. It works.